# AJAX not working when pressing submit button

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am practicing the basics of AJAX.

When I click Submit nothing happens.

Here’s my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>FIRST AJAX!</title>

<script>
function alertMe(){
    var field1 = document.getElementById("Field1").value;
    var parser = "parse.php";
    var values = "name="+filed1;
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("POST", parser, true);
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = xml.responseText;
        }
    }
    xml.send(values);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = " Loading ... ";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="Field1" id="Field1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Fsend" onClick="alertMe();"/>
    <p id="output"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` and `onclick` instead of `onClick`.

Comment: Standard attributes should always be lowercase, do not use onClick.  Also, if you are following the standards, input elements should always be contained within a form element, although this shouldn't affect the functionality if you are using type="button", it's just proper.

Comment: At one point you’ve got `filed1` instead of `field1` — it’s a typo. Otherwise it should be working fine. As far as I know this should get flagged, unfortunately…

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are declaring a variable called field1, and then calling it as fiLEd1.

Try checking the console for errors, it's always useful

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = "name="+filed1;
```

has a typo, should be...

```
var values = "name="+field1;
```

Also, input elements should be within a form and you probably want to use type="button" since you are not submitting the form.  Finally, all standard attributes should be in lowercase, should be onclick, not onClick.

```
<!doctype html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>FIRST AJAX!</title> <script>
function alertMe(){
var field1 = document.getElementById("Field1").value; 
var parser = "parse.php";
var values = "name="+field1; 
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open("POST", parser, true);
xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if ( xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200){
         document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = xml.responseText; 
     }   
}   
xml.send(values);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = " Loading ... ";
} 
</script> 
</head>

<body><form>
<input type="text" name="Field1" id="Field1"/> 
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="Fsend" onclick="alertMe();"/>
</form> <p id="output"></p>
</body> </html>
```